# Какой самый правильный и провереный способ проверки наличия записи в таблице в PL/SQL блоке?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Какой есть правильный и провереный способ проверки наличия записи в таблице, когда использую PL/SQL блок?

Например, есть таблица `PERSON (ID, Name)`. Очевидно, что нельзя сделать (если только нет какого-нибудь секретного метода) что-то в этом роде:

```
BEGIN 
  IF EXISTS SELECT id FROM person WHERE ID = 10; 
    -- делать что-то если запись найдена
  ELSE
    -- делать что-то если запись еще не сушествует
  END IF;
END;
```

Так что использую такой стандартный способ решения:

```
DECLARE
  tmp NUMBER;
BEGIN 
  SELECT id INTO tmp FROM person WHERE id = 10; 
    -- делать что-то если запись найдена
EXCEPTION
  WHEN no_data_found THEN
    -- делать что-то если запись еще не сушествует
END;
```

Однако, не уверен, принято ли это так делать, или есть лучший способ проверки.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Proper way of checking if row exists in table in pl/sql block](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21140868/6571020) от участника [@devBem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3053224/devbem)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/21140868

Answer (score 3):

Не стоит помещать код с обычной логикой в блок исключений, там должна быть только обработка исключений.

Сначала проверьте, есть ли записи, и далее реализуйте логику по результатам проверки:

```
declare
    cursor cur is select 1 from person where id=10; 
    found boolean := false; 
begin 
    open cur; found := cur%found;
    close cur;

    if found then 
        null; -- делать что-то если запись найдена
    else 
        null; -- делать что-то если запись еще не сушествует
    end if;
exception when others then 
    null; -- делать что-то с исключением
end;
/
```

Или так с неявным курсором:

```
declare
    found boolean := false; 
begin 
    <<checkIfExists>>
    for r in (select 1 from person where id=10) loop
        found := true;
        exit checkIfExists;
    end loop;
    if found then 
        null; -- делать что-то если запись найдена
    else 
        null; -- делать что-то если запись еще не сушествует
    end if;
exception when others then
    null; -- делать что-то с исключением
end;
/
```

Answer (score 2):

Не стал бы вставлять обычный код в блок исключений.

Просто проверьте, есть ли строки, которые отвечают вашему условию, и продолжайте дальше:

```
declare
    any_rows_found number;
begin
    select count(*)
    into   any_rows_found
    from   my_table
    where  rownum = 1 and
         ... other conditions ...

    if any_rows_found = 1 then
        ...
    else
        ...
    end if;
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21142768) участника [@David Aldridge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6742/david-aldridge)</sub>